# How to use shorter path to get vuex contents?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my vuex /store/state.js I have an export default that looks like this:

```
export default {
  foo: {
    bar:{
      tar: {
        info: 42
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

So, whenever I want to access `info`, I usually do in my methods like this;

```
methods: {
  getInfo () {
   return this.$store.state.foo.bar.tar.info
  }
}
```

This is just for a demo purpose, and mine is actually a bit worse, but I ended up doing the same so, I tried minimize the code using a computed prop:

```
computed: {
  info () {
    return this.$store.state.foo.bar.tar.info
  }
}
```

Now, I just call `info` but still, not sure if there is a better way to get values, because sometimes I just need to call info only one in a page, so I have to use the full path or create a computed property for it.

Is there any other way to do this

Comment: You could write a getter inside the vuex state.

Comment: @puelo This is actually something I've been trying to learn about but no idea how it is done. Do you have any links?

Comment: A getter could help but you should ask yourself if you really need to nest something that deep. If you are going that specific, chances are that your store might do too much and you simply need to split up your store into multiple modules.

Comment: @hidar https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: I'm with Stephan-v. I always try to avoid to put complex nested objects into the state. About getters, the documentation explains quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always separate vuex into separated modules. For instance if you have store for foo module. I will create file named `foo.js` which contains

```
const fooModule = {
  state: {
    foo: {
      bar: {
        tar: {
          info: 42
        }
      }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    info (state) {
      return state.foo.bar.tar.info
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setInfo (state, payload) {
      state.foo.bar.tar.info = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getInfo ({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setInfo', payload)
    }
  }
}

export default fooModule
```

Then in your main index vuex, import the module like this way

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import fooModule from './foo.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    fooModule
  }
})

export default store
```

Then if you wanna get info, you just write your code like this

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getInfo'
    ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@jefry Dewangga has the the right idea but introducing mapGetters is unnecessary.

VueX by default includes namespacing for modules which allows us to load multiple modules into a store and then reference them with or without namespacing them and it'll figure the rest out.

For Instance if we have the structure of

```
|-- store
  |-- Modules
    |-- module1.js
    |-- module2.js
    |-- module3.js
|-- index.js
```

We can use index in such a way to bind all of our modules into our Vuex store doing the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import modules from './modules'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules
})
```

An example of our module1 could be:

```
const state = {
    LoggedIn: true
}

const mutations = {
    LOGIN(state) {
        state.LoggedIn = true;
    },
    LOGOFF(state) {
        state.LoggedIn = false;
    }
}

const actions = {}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

This in turn gives us the ability to say:

```
this.$store.commit('LOGIN');
```

Note that we haven't used any namespacing but as we haven't included any duplicate mutations from within our modules were absolutely fine to implicitly declare this.

Now if we want to use namespacing we can do the following which will explicitly use out module:

```
this.$store.module1.commit('LOGIN');
```

MapGetters are useful but they provide a lot of extra overhead when we can neatly digest out modules without having to continuously map everything, unless well we find the mapping useful. A great example of when `MapGetters` become handy is when we are working many components down in a large project and we want to be able to look at our source without having to necessarily worry about the frontend implementation.

Comment: I noticed that this could be seen as going off topic, but adopting a module based strategy would helpfully stop him using deep nesting.